# How to make Widget constrained to two other Widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to make one `Widget` to have constraints to two other ones in the same container (`Column`/`Row`)?

This is a pretty common case when designing list items. The UI should be scalable (for instance when the end user increases Font Size manually).

**I do not accept answers with any hardcoded numbers**. Just logical linking. I also do not accept answers with any 3rd party solution.

Here's the UI spec:

[image]

So the requirements are the folowing:

- the `Text` scalable widget is a master one to which `Icon` is constrained by centring it vertically
- at the same time the Bottom text is constrained with it's start left edge to `Text` left edge

This is very simple to be solved with `ConstraintLayout` in Android.

Comment: use `Stack` wrapped with `LayoutBuilder` widget - there is no `ConstraintLayout` equivalent in flutter

Comment: or if you really want to have the full control of children positioning use `CustomMultiChildLayout`, the docs say: "A widget that uses a delegate to size and position multiple children.

The delegate can determine the layout constraints for each child and can decide where to position each child. The delegate can also determine the size of the parent, but the size of the parent cannot depend on the sizes of the children."

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @pskink I tried using `CustomMultiChildLayout`. It is not an easy API as it works with `Size` directly. Hence, in order to compensate for the fact that texts can increate the height (or span multiple lines) here is the solution I have drafted:

(The `Bottom Text` was replaced by `Button Bar`, but the requirements are the same in regards of layouting sibling `Widget`s)

Result when the text is larger than icon:

[image]

Result when the text is smaller than icon:

[image]

Here is the code:

```dart
        CustomMultiChildLayout(
          children: [
            LayoutId(
              id: _ICON,
              child: CustomIcon(),
            ),
            LayoutId(
              id: _TEXT,
              child: Text("<SOME_DYNAMIC_TEXT>"),
            ),
            LayoutId(
              id: _BUTTON_BAR,
              child: CustomButtonBar(),
            )
          ],
          delegate: _LayoutDelegate(),
        ),
```

Ids:

```dart
const int _ICON = 1;
const int _TEXT = 2;
const int _BUTTON_BAR = 3;
```

`LayoutDelegate`:

```dart
class _LayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    final Size iconSize = layoutChild(_ICON, BoxConstraints());
    // AppTheme.largeSpacing is predefined to 24.0
    final double iconPlusPaddingWidth = iconSize.width + AppTheme.largeSpacing;
    final Size textSize = layoutChild(
      _TEXT,
      BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: size.width - iconPlusPaddingWidth),
    );
    final Size buttonBarSize = layoutChild(_BUTTON_BAR, BoxConstraints());

    final double height = iconSize.height > textSize.height
        ? iconSize.height / 2
        : textSize.height / 2;

    final double startX = iconSize.width + AppTheme.largeSpacing;

    positionChild(
      _ICON,
      Offset(0, height - iconSize.height / 2),
    );
    positionChild(
      _TEXT,
      Offset(
        startX,
        height - textSize.height / 2,
      ),
    );
    positionChild(
      _BUTTON_BAR,
      Offset(
        startX,
        textSize.height + AppTheme.largeSpacing,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Last notes - it is not a straightforward API when devs still need to calculate sizes through variables and use them for positioning.

Comment: i did not try it, but what if the text is really, really long? i mean you passed `tightFor` with width only, for looooong text it's height can be larger that `size.height` minus the height of bottom buttons

Comment: @pskink then the text overflows but... without's Flutter overflow error. I have read in docs that `CustomMultiChildLayout` does not seem to be suitable to handle such cases. As:
`/// The delegate can also determine the size of the parent, but the size of the parent cannot depend on the sizes of the children.`

So no way to tell this container to be as tall as its content, so it would be properly resolved in something like `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: yes, that's right, parent size cannot depend on any child size but you can limit the text height do that it doesn't overflow bottom buttons and parents edges

Comment: I can. But I would like to find a solution without such limits.